# In WooCommerce filter the available Payment Methods by User Role

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

Is it possible to filter available payment methods to certain user roles just using the WooCommerce configuration? Without adding anything to any template file I mean. What I want to achieve is to give the possibility to pay with credit card only to certain users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible by WooCommerce default configuration.

You have to install below plugin.

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-role-based-payment-shipping-methods/18953727

or programmatically, you can refer below link.

https://businessbloomer.com/disable-payment-gateway-specific-user-role-woocommerce/

Answer (score 15):

You can use following:

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
  function filter_gateways($gateways)
  {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $role = $current_user->roles;
      global $woocommerce;
      /* add your user role in condition and payment method which you need to unset*/
      if ($role[0] == 'administrator') {
          unset($gateways['cod']);
      }
      return $gateways;
  }
```